# Verification of proof : The nth Harmonic number is never an integer

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, p-adic-number-theory

Let $H_n$ be the nth harmonic number, then $$H_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{i}=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{n!}{i}$$
Let $v_2(n!)=a$.
Note that if we can show $$v_2\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{n!}{i}\right)<v_2(n!)$$ we're done.

Since $$v_2\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{n!}{i}\right)=v_2\left(\frac{n!}{2^a}\right)=v_2(n!)-a<v_2(n!)$$
That completes the proof. The thing that I'm not sure of is the generalization of this lemma that I've used $$v_p(a+b)=v_p(b)$$ whenever $v_p(b)<v_p(a)$.
Its generalization is as follows,

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of positive integers s.t. $v_p(a_n)>...>v_p(a_1)$ then $$v_p\left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)=v_p(a_1)$$ But again I'm not sure whether it's true or not.

Comment: Basic properties of the $p-$adic valuation can be read about [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order) or elsewhere online.

Comment: The way you write your "generalization" it has obvious counterexamples if $j \ge 2$ (namely, set $a_0 = ... = a_{j-1} = 0 \neq a_j$) but is true if you mean $1=j$, as can be easily seen via induction.